# Rock Paper scissors logic issues

Tags: javascript, logic

Just started learning Javascript with The Odin Project. Building Rock paper Scissors and I'm trying to build my logic "oN My oWn" but kinda stuck.

I have the computer and input from the gamer. However, one returns a string while the other is a number. solution?

also, I think my game logic is flawed.

````
const rps = ["ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"];

let computerPlay =  Math.floor(Math.random() * rps.length);

console.log(rps[computerPlay]);

let playerSelection = window.prompt("ROCK, PAPER, or SCISSORS?")

console.log(playerSelection, computerPlay);
/* Need to change both to strings? */


/* Game Logic*/

if (playerSelection === "ROCK") {
    if (computerPlay === "ROCK")
        return "TIE: Both selected ROCK";
    else if (computerPlay === "PAPER")
        return "You Lose! PAPER beats ROCK";
    else (computerPlay === "SCISSORS")
        return "You Won! ROCK beats SCISSORS";
} 
else if (playerSelection === "PAPER") {
    if (computerPlay === "PAPER")
        return "TIE: Both selected PAPER";
    else if (computerPlay === "ROCK")
        return "You Won! PAPER beats ROCK";
    else (computerPlay === "SCISSORS")
        return "You Lose! SCISSORS beats PAPER";
} else if (playerSelection === "SCISSORS") {
    if (computerPlay === "SCISSORS")
        return "TIE: Both selected SCISSORS";
    else if (computerPlay === "PAPER")
        return "You Won! SCISSORS beats PAPER";
    else (computerPlay === "ROCK")
        return "You Lose! ROCK beats SCISSORS";}```
````

Comment: You need to set `computerPlay` to `rps[computerPlay]` at some point, or introduce another variable. You're comparing the *index* of the computer pick instead of the value.

Answer (score 2):

After a basic Recon, you have your random number in `computerPlay` and you are trying to compare this to the user's input which is totally wrong. You need to compare `rps[computerPlay]` to the users response.